# Skipping lags in autoregressive modeling?

Tags: regression, time-series, autoregressive

is it possible to skip immediately preceding time points? So that, if, for example, you are using model order 2, that is, two time points, but not the two immediately previous time points, but rather, say for example, skipping 2 points, and then using those two points.  So, e.g., it would be y=x(t-3) + x(t-4).

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Thanks! What is it called?  How is the "model order" distinguished from the "skipping"?  Can you point me to it anywhere in the literature??

Comment: Richard Hardy, how?

Comment: You have $y$ on the left and $x$ on the right, so this is not an autoregression at all. If you really meant to have something like $y_t = \phi_3 y_{t-3} + \phi_4 y_{t-4} + \varepsilon_t$, then this is just an AR(4) which is restricted to have $\phi_1 = \phi_2 = 0$.

Comment: Thanks, and for correcting my mistake.  Is there a difference in calling an AR(4) model with those restrictions, versus calling it and AR(2) model with skipping the first two points?

Comment: I think we are describing the same process, but an "AR(4) with restrictions" is a special case of a well-established family of models, whereas "skipping the first two points" is probably not clear unless you explain it. Also, the "order" of an AR process matches the "order" of its characteristic polynomial, but your "AR(2) with skipping" has a characteristic polynomial of order 4. For consistency, the number in brackets should be the largest lag (4), not the number of lags (2).

Comment: Chris thank you again! Would it be possible to talk with you about this issue? Just briefly!